# Programmatically determine Destination ViewController

Tags: storyboard, segue, xcode5

I'm a storyboard neophyte and would like to determine the destination UIViewController programmatically.

The current (default) is: `(root VC) --> segue --> destination VC`.

Desired: `(root VC) -->seque -->VC1, (root VC)-->segue-->VC2`, ... on demand.

I've using Xcode's utility-application template that comes with the main & flip UIViewControllers, using a storyboard.

I would like to be able to change the 'flip' or destination UIViewController programmatically.

All the XIBs that I used are within the storyboard.  I've added a second destination UIViewController which is currently autonomous but don't know how to incorporate it to be toggled with the existing destination UIViewController.

Can I use the storyboard paradigm and if so, how?
Or must I resort to working only with XIBs?

Answer (score 0):

you can create two segues

```
(root VC) -->seque1 -->VC1
(root VC) -->seque2 -->VC2
```

using the story board, give different identifiers to them. Then call the desired segue programatically using

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1identifier" sender:nil];
```